# Is there any evidence that this character is really dead?

Tags: supernatural

(Possible spoilers for Supernatural seasons 8–10)

In *Supernatural* Season 7 a character called [Frank Deveraux](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Devereaux) apparently died. But for several reasons he could still be alive?

- He was highly intelligent and he was paranoid so maybe he faked his death.
- We never really saw a body? Or did we?
- He also repaid the favour to Bobby so maybe, he decided to move on.

The [Wikia](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Devereaux) also thinks that he could still be alive.

> Though it seemed that Frank was killed by the Leviathans it is
> possible that he could still be alive, due to the nature of his
> paranoia he could have faked his death to avoid the Leviathans.

While this quote is not my logic, there is no hard evidence he really died.

Also, the circumstances in which he died seem fishy. He helped Dean, sent him away and told him to meet later. This gave him time to prepare the scene and to make a clean getaway. This supports the fact that he was moving on since he already repaid the favour the Bobby did for him.

> Sam and Dean set out to meet Frank at the end of the episode, but
> instead find his RV, filled with smashed electronics and blood.

**Am I missing something or is this character really dead?**

Any information about where Frank's body went  would be appreciated, as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### There is no definitive evidence to say he is dead or since that moment, any evidence to the contrary.

- We can say this much about Frank Deveraux: his level of paranoia and preparation were legendary. If there was anyone who might have escaped the Leviathans by faking his own death, Frank Deveraux would be that person.
- Since the Winchesters have been using the **[Men of Letters Honeycomb Hideout](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/The_Men-of-Letters_Bunker)**, they have less need of a character like Frank Deveraux so it may be the writers have simply not had a reason to explain is escape and leave him "dead" in case they need a story thread that Frank could fit into.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much what I came up with. But what happened to the body, what's the explanation for that.

Comment: If he is dead, the Leviathans just ate him. They do that... According to the Leviathans, we're delicious...

Comment: But that would have left pieces of Frank everywhere, all that was left was blood, to my knowledge. The Leviathans were messy eaters, surely there would have been more of a mess.

Comment: I think it depends on the Leviathan and what they were eating. I always thought they were inclined to eat everything, bones and all. That might have been the only clue that Frank wasn't dead. One season to go. Maybe we will get a confirmation one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

In "Out with the Old" he says he "could be in Tromso" right now, where there is no Leviathan activity.  To me, this would suggest a supernatural reason for no Leviathan activity.  Perhaps some sort of Purgatory black hole that would suck the Leviathan back into Purgatory.  Regardless, I can very much see him saying that as his final farewell to Sam and Dean prior to hitching a fishing boat to Tromso, Norway.  I look forward, hopefully not in vain, to his return.  His was a strong character.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that makes me believe that Frank is still kicking. Frank maybe was inteligent and all but he wasn't the fighter type. Yes maybe he shot a gun to a Leviathan but this woudn't explain all this mess. I believe that if Leviathans were sent to do him in, it would be much less messier than it was